# installer generated by install4j is not working using -q -varfile options

Tags: install4j

My software is generated using install4j. When I install it with -q -varfile options (eg. example.sh -q -varfile responce.varfile) then i get below error.
I am using install4j 5.1.6 verions with java 1.7

What am I missing here?

```
Starting Installer ...

In application "Installer", property "Progress interface creation script":
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:711)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.getParentIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.isElevatedHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.helperUnsupported(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.getProgressInterface(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.getProgressInterface(Unknown Source)
    at I4jScript_Internal_1.eval(I4jScript_Internal_1.java:18)
    at I4jScript_Internal_1.evaluate(I4jScript_Internal_1.java:24)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.Script.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(Unknown Source)
```

Please find the following screenshot and script -

Allow unattended mode -> Progress interface creation script :-(screenshot attached below.)

[image]

`UnattendedProgressInterface unattend =(UnattendedProgressInterface)context.getProgressInterface();
 unattend.setVisible(true);
 return unattend ;`

Comment: Do you call context.getProgressInterface() in an elevated "Run script" action?

Comment: Hi,
This code is already written in installer -> Allow unattended mode -> 
UnattendedProgressInterface unattend =(UnattendedProgressInterface)context.getProgressInterface();
unattend.setVisible(true);
return unattend ;

Also elevation privilages are given to maximum. But its still not working.

Above code is written at installer level, do I need to write it for any particular step/script?
Where am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Can you add the offending script to your question?

Comment: Edited the question, added image and code. Does it make the question clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress interface creation script is intended so that you can supply a custom implementation. What you are doing can only lead to a stack overflow error.

If you want to show the window with a progress bar during an unattended installation, pass

-q -splash "Title"

on the command line or set the "Default execution mode" property to "Unattended mode with progress dialog".

Comment: I am not able to understand you properly. how we can set "Default execution mode" to "Unattended mode with progress dialog" can you please give me some easy steps or example, So it will help full for me. and with -q -splash "title" option what will be title it should be screen title ya only simple message.

Comment: Go to the Installer->Screens & Actions step, select the installer, then look for the "Default execution mode" property in the list of properties on the right side. "title" is whatever you want as the title of the progress window.

Comment: i have configure above settings but still getting same error.below example of run installer commandline using -splash option.

Ex. bash example.sh -q -splash "Title"  -varfile response.varfile

Comment: You have to delete the script that causes this error.

Comment: Our installer runs by default in GUI mode. We want to support console mode as well by providing -q option and provide a var file.
What needs to be done for this ? Should we attach a script under "Allow unattended Mode" option ? If yes, what it should be ?

Comment: You have to delete the progress interface creation script that is shown in your screenshot.